# Mapping rational numbers to a fixed real number by a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Let $x$ be a fixed real number and let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rational numbers. It is known that $\mathbb{R}$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$ and thus there exists some homomorphisms. Can we obtain the real number $x$ by a *finite* sequence of homomorphisms from an (appropriately chosen) rational number $q$?

Homomorphism takes the usual meaning that 
$$
f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b); \\
f(ab)=f(a)f(b);\\
f(1_{\mathbb{Q}})=1_{\mathbb{R}}.
$$

Comment: With your definition, the only homomorphism appears to be the map $y \mapsto y$. This is because you will have $f(n) = n$ for $n$ an integer, and then $m = f(m) = f( m/n \cdot n) = f(m/n) \cdot f(n) =  f(m/n) \cdot n$, so that $f(m/n) = m/n$ for $m, n$ integers, $n \ne 0$.

Comment: A more general case of the answer above is that for a field extention $L$ of $K$, all automorphisms fix the prime subfield. Here, the prime subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: “Thus there exist some homomorphisms”: Plenty of field homomorphisms into the complexes, but none as automorphisms of $\Bbb R$, save the identity.